# How to deal with accidental overdose of antibiotics on a cat?

Tags: cats, medicines

Last week I rescued a badly injured cat from the streets and have been since taking care of him. He's not playful or aggressive or have any cat-like attitude in him at all, which was worrying me. But today when I ran out of his antibiotic pill and had to buy more I discovered that the lady who sold me the antibiotics for the first time gave me wrong dosage.

We were supposed to give him one and a half pill of 75mg (totalling about 110mg) but instead we were giving him 450mg! I can't get in touch with the vet who was seeing him because she's traveling and his consult is only in four days, but I'm really worried about him. But if I go to another vet I'll have to pay another consult and I already spent tons of money on medicine and procedures to clean the infected wound (to have an idea, the muscle is exposed, he was being eaten alive by larvae).

But how worried should I be about this? Do I suspend the antibiotics completely? Do I take him right away to see a vet? Or should I wait four days?

By the way he's eating and drinking water properly and using the litter box, although his feces is VERY soft.

Comment: What was the antibiotic?  How many doses have you given? How long ago? Dose frequency? Many antibiotics have a very wide dose range, but it is impossible to provide any advice without knowing what drug was given and exactly how you have been giving it.

Comment: Just call the other vet, make sure you have to medication's name at hand. I'm pretty sure they won't mind telling you on the phone whether you should be worried or not or come in to check (or which symptoms to be wary of), especially considering in many cases whoever answers the phone might be able to help you already. There's always the chance they're lying to make money, but being honest might earn them more customers in the future, especially if they're unknown to them.

Comment: @HarryV.. The antibiotic is rilexin, it was given twice a day for 8 days. But I guess I'll call the other vet on the phone like Mario suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you still have a to wait a few days to see the vet I would go to a local pet store and find some probiotics or Bene-Bac to add to what he's eating It'll help provide beneficial bacteria in the digestive tract that may have been lost due to the over use of antibiotics, this is probably causing the loose stool, but a vet would dive deeper into the loose stool, especially if it in unrelated to the antibiotics. Extra fluids will help with the diarrhea too.

Typically the largest fear with too much antibiotics is a yeast infection caused by an overproduction of white blood cells in the body; produced in the body to fight infection. Homeopathic antifungals will fix that, and prescription antifungals will treat it even quicker IF that is the result.

If there are no new signs of illness the cat should remain fine, you'd see issues soon after digestion. A vet visit or phone call is always a good decision, as mentioned by previous comments.

By the way, you can post your own answer to inform others of your experience if you take him to the vet or if you call your vet; let the public know what the veterinarian said!

Comment: Hello and thank you so much for the answer. In the end I did buy probiotics and when we went to the vet his stool was much firmer. She did indicate that we kept with the probiotics for a few more days. His only visible symptom from the excess of antibitoics was the loose stool.