# I accidentally overdosed my kitten on his antibiotic; what should I do?

Tags: cats, safety, medicines

What should I do? I accidentally overdosed my kitten on his antibiotic; his proper dose was 1:30 and it was accidentally given to him again at 5:30. The antibiotic is “Clavamox drops amoxicillin and clavulanate potassium for oral suspension usp”.

Comment: In this case the first thing you can always do is call your vet, or if they are not available, call an emergency clinic. This is a way to get information quickly.

Comment: Twice the suggested dose is not a huge overdose. There is no reason to be alarmed whatsoever.

Comment: Apart from the schedule did you exceed actual dosage? Did you mistake mg/ml maybe? Was it administered by a dropper, or needle-less syringe?

Answer (score 4):

1. Please read the package leaflet and follow the instructions given there.
2. If you cannot find the leaflet or any helpful information in it, treat the overdose as if it was a regular dose. Do not skip one or more doses, just continue the treatment at the regular interval with the appropriate dosage.
3. If your cat starts panting while in rest or hiding more than regular, becomes lethargic or refuses to eat or drink anything at all for 24 hours, call your vet and get instructions from them. This would be a medical emergency and you should not wait for strangers on the internet to tell you what to do.

Some vomiting, diarrhea and a loss of appetite are common side effects of antibiotics and usually no reason to call the vet. If they become so severe that your cat becomes weak and lethargic, call the vet anyways. Feeding some probiotics you can buy at pet stores or online helps restoring the balance of her gut biome, which in turn should help with the diarrhea.

Don't ever give your cat medicine or probiotics intended for humans without explicit instructions from your vet ([read more here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/726/12501)). If you cannot find any probiotics for cats, feed her one teaspoon of natural plain yogurt (which **must not contain xylithol**) a day instead.

Please also read the information given in [this related question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/17234/12501).